# How to get element margin in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an slider in React.

My component is as follows :

```
outterDivStyles() {
        return {
            position: "relative",
            width: "100%",
            overflow: "hidden",
            height: this.props.height || 200
        }
    }

innerDivStyles(){
    return {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: this.state.left,
        right: 0,
        width: "1000%",
        transition: "left .5s",
        transitionTimingFunction: "ease"
    }
}

renderArrows(){
    return (
        <div className="next-prev" style={{height: this.props.height || 200}}>
            <div onClick={this.prevSlide.bind(this)}><img src={images.slider_arrow_left_png} /></div>
            <div onClick={this.nextSlide.bind(this)}><img src={images.slider_arrow_right_png} /></div>
        </div>
    )
}


render(){
return(
<div>
    <div ref="detailsOutterDiv" className="detailsOutterDiv" style={this.outterDivStyles()}>
         <div ref="detailsInnerDiv" className="detailsInnerDiv" style={this.innerDivStyles()}>
              {this.carInfo().photos.map((p, i) => {
                  return (
                      <div key={i} className="slide"><img src={p.image_url}/></div>
                  );
               })}
         </div>
         {this.renderArrows()}
    </div>
</div>
)
}
```

The css is as follows :

```
.slide{
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slide img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


@media (min-width: 1599px) {
  .detailsOutterDiv .detailsInnerDiv div{
    width: (10% / 3);

  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get width plus margin of the div with class `slide`.

I try to do it with :

`let slideWidth = this.refs["detailsInnerDiv"].childNodes[0].style.marginRight;`

But `slideWidth` is 0.

Any advice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this.

```
let node = this.refs["detailsInnerDiv"].childNodes[0] //assuming this as your target node
let nodeStyle = window.getComputedStyle(node)
let slideMarginRight = nodeStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-right')
```

For more info refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Hope this helps!